# Progress ABL - strip and add to temp table

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm coming from a Java/.NET background and trying to learn ABL but the difference in structure and the limited information on the internet is making it hard. What I want to do is import data from a text file which is in the following format:

```
john     smith     52     ceo
...
```

line by line, and take the different parts based on the position of the character. For example, positions 1-10 are for the first name, 10-20 second name and so on... **Do I have to use entry for that?** If so can someone more experienced give an example how to do it cause I'm quite confused. Then I need to add a record for each line to a temp-table I have created called tt-employee. **How do I go about doing that?**

I apologise if my question is a bit vague but as I said, I am new to this so I'm still figuring things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If space is a delimiter you can use the IMPORT statement.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt-employee NO-UNDO
    FIELD firstname AS CHARACTER
    FIELD lastname  AS CHARACTER
    FIELD age       AS INTEGER
    FIELD empTitle  AS CHARACTER.

INPUT FROM c:\temp\indata.dat.
REPEAT:
    CREATE tt-employee.
    IMPORT DELIMITER " " tt-employee.
END.
INPUT CLOSE.
```

However if there isn't a delimiter but rather a fixed record with (as you mention) you can do something like this (error checking and correct record lengths needs to be applied).

```
/* Skipping temp-table definition - copy-paste from above */
DEFINE VARIABLE cRow AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

INPUT FROM c:\temp\indata.dat.
REPEAT:

    IMPORT UNFORMATTED cRow.
    /* You could replace 0 with a higher number that qualifies a record so 
       SUBSTRING doesn't return an error if reading past end of line */
    IF LENGTH(cRow) > 0 THEN DO:
        CREATE tt-employee.
        ASSIGN 
            tt-employee.firstname = SUBSTRING(cRow, 1, 10)
            tt-employee.lastname  = SUBSTRING(cRow, 11, 10)
            tt-employee.age       = INTEGER(SUBSTRING(cRow, 21, 2))
            tt-employee.empTitle  = SUBSTRING(cRow, 23, 10) NO-ERROR.
    END.
END.
INPUT CLOSE.
```

There are several places on the web to look for OpenEdge information:

Official knowledgebase - http://knowledgebase.progress.com/

Official community - https://community.progress.com/?Redirected=true

More communities - http://www.progresstalk.com/ and http://oehive.org/